# Develop PyQt app in 32-bit Windows, deploy to 64-bit Linux?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm brand new to Python/PyQt/Qt development. I need to develop an application using this library+framework combination. The application is to run on a Linux box that currently has Python 2.7.1 and PyQt4 installed, therefore these are the versions I must target. This condition is being imposed and cannot be changed. It should also run on Windows and Mac but my first goal is the Linux machine.

I'm trying to set up the development environment on my desktop Windows machine for the first time so that I can use it to develop on and am having great difficulty. I'm virtually certain that the Linux machine that I will deploy to (the one mentioned above) is 64-bit. I am able to find 32-bit and 64-bit PyQt installers ("PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x32.exe" and "PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x64.exe") here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pyqt/activity/?page=0&limit=100#562b9e5b5fcbc913f3ef2aa2

However, I am only able to locate a 32-bit installer for Qt itself ("qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw482-4.8.7") here: https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.7/

Is it possible for me to set up a 32-bit development environment with which to develop my PyQt application on and then deploy to the 64-bit Linux box so that the Linux version will use the 64-bit frameworks installed?

Comment: The python code is cross-platform, you will not have any problem executing the code in linux

Comment: I agree that the Python part of it should not be a problem, but what about the interface part built with PyQt?

Comment: I have worked on projects in PyQt and I have not had problems running them on Windows, Linux or Mac.

Comment: I continually answer problems for all the OS supported by python, the problem maybe serious in the PyQt versions, but they would be minimal.